# @InjectParam in JAX-RS Core

Tags: parameters, jax-rs, parameter-passing

In an earlier version of our application, we have used the annotation [@InjectParam](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html) of Jersey. Now we want to use JAX-RS core. (Imports only java.ws.rs ..... No dependencies on an implementation of JAX-RS) We used @InjectParam as a wrapper for different @QueryParam. So can be very long, same parameter lists prevented.

Is there an alternative for @InjectParam in JAX-RS? Can someone give me a hint?

With @InjectParam I want to avoid long method bodies, such as:

```
    @GET
        @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
        public Response listClusters(@QueryParam(ClusterFilter.NODE) String node,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.CLUSTERNAME) String clustername,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.CNAME) String cname,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.STAGE) String stage,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.INSTALLATIONVARIANT) String installationvariant,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.BUILDNUMBER) String buildnumber,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.LAS) String las,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.P3270) String p3270,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.LASPRETEST) String lasPretest,
                @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.P3270PRETEST) String p3270Pretest) {
.
.
.
```

In JEE5 with Jersey we had:

```
public Response listClustersAsHtml(@InjectParam ClusterFilterParameterConverter cFPConverter) {.....
```

Definition of ClusterFilterParameterConverter was:

```
public class ClusterFilterParameterConverter {
    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.NODE)
    private String node;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.CLUSTERNAME)
    private String clustername;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.CNAME)
    private String cname;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.STAGE)
    private String stage;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.INSTALLATIONVARIANT)
    private String installationvariant;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.BUILDNUMBER)
    private String buildnumber;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.LAS)
    private String las;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.P3270)
    private String p3270;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.LASPRETEST)
    private String lasPretest;

    @QueryParam(ClusterFilter.P3270PRETEST)
    private String p3270Pretest;....
```

Comment: Can you provide a clearer use case of how you're using `@InjectParam` in your code?  Sample code would help.

Comment: I editet my question. I hope it is now little more clearly

Comment: Can't tell by the question if you're using JAX-RS 1 or 2, but for 2, there's `@BeanParam`. This situation is exactly what it's used for. Prior to JAX-RS 2, there's no such annotation.

Comment: Thanx, we use JAX-RS 1.1 / JEE6